# Rails, can't load data from fixtures that have HABTM relationshionship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, fixtures, functional-testing

I'm new to rails and testing and have a problem with loading my fixtures.

> **payment.yml**
>     payment:
>       name: something
>       amount: 1.5
>       event: some_event
>       user: some_user
>       description: long text
>       users: some_user, some_user2
>     
>     
>     **users.yml**
>     some_user:
>       email: test@test.com
>       nick: name
>     
>     some_user2:
>       email: test@test.com
>       nick: name

okey, so the problem is that when I'm doing the functionaltest for creating a payment

> test "should create payment" do
>       assert_difference('Payment.count') do
>         post :create, :payment => @payment.attributes
>       end

it just sends

> < Payment id: nil, name: "something", amount: 1.5, event_id: 972288058, user_id: 63246679, created_at: "2010-11-05 19:56:53", updated_at: "2010-11-05 19:56:53", description: "long text" >

and not the users array with multiple users. I use the "user" to define who owns the payment and users (in a seperate join table) as a list of users sharing the payment.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

here is the model for payments

> class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base 
>       has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
>       belongs_to :event
>       belongs_to :user
>       has_and_belongs_to_many :users
>   end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put the model for payment?  I had something similar and the problem was that the model was different.  For example, if it's a ActiveRecord class, you have to check how it and its relationships.  For example, if the event is actually an "event_id" that belongs_to an "event" class, then you should put something similar to this:

```
payment.yml
payment:
  name: something
  amount: 1.5
  event_id: 1
  user_id: 1
  ...
user.yml
   id: 1
   name: David Smith
   status: Branch Manager
  ...
event.yml
  id: 1
  name: overdraft charge
```

Comment: but how about that I'm having one user that is "belongs_to" and one users that is "has_and_belongs_to_many"?

Comment: Ruby does that, but you still have to handle it in the fixture yml file.  In my example, lets say I have a relationship of one-to-one with payment and user.  Also, I have a one-to-one with payment and event.  For example, in my payment model I would have something like this: belongs_to : user, :foreign_key => "user_id". Again, this is in the model portion. Check this link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html and look for "Label references for associations (belongs_to, has_one, has_many)"